# How get all matches from same objects by preg_match_all?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a table:

```
<table class="table_class" >
    <tr>
        <td>key</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The table may have any count of `<tr>`

I have regexp:

```
<table class="table_class">(<tr.*?><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td></tr>){1,}</table>
```

But matches array contains only last match.

Just `(<tr.*?><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td></tr>)` I can not do, because other table will may be.

Before apply preg_match_all I delete whitespaces.
How do this? Thanks!

UPD: example with a few tables

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>key</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="table_class" >
    <tr>
        <td>key</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

yet, I will want to know why my regexp match only last `<tr>`))

Comment: First off, your example table has no `<th>` tags...  Can you give a full example with more than one table?  Also, you're not allowing any whitespace between tags in your regex, though your example does have whitespace.

Comment: Use a parser, not a regex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php.

Comment: ok, I will try parser. Just I always thought that regexp more faster)

Comment: yes, I do not add whitespace in regexp, just I delete them before apply preg_match_all. 
Oo..<th> tags, sorry, just one site have this HTML))
I corrected example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now *usually* I'm first to say it's fine to use regexps to extract data from HTML occasionally, as it's oft just faster and more efficient to do so than using a real parser. This is not one of those cases as the structure of the HTML is more than relevant.

Instead consider something like this:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML(<<<HTML
<table class="table_class" >
    <tr><td>key1</td><td>value1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>key2</td><td>value2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>key3</td><td>value3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>key4</td><td>value4</td></tr>
</table>
HTML
);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $row) { 
  foreach($row->getElementsByTagName('td') as $cell)
    var_dump($cell->nodeValue);
}
```

[See it in action here](https://eval.in/483553).

Comment: what If HTML will contains very very many tables?))

Comment: Then you would `getElementsByTagName('table')` first and look by class, index or ID for the right one.

Comment: Thanks, I used parser, but from link of @chris85, I found parser which can use jQuery selectors